# sails.js asynchronous issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, sails.js

I want to test the asynchronous performance of sails.js, so I wrote the following code to wait for 10 seconds (I think the code should be executed asynchronously due to the callback function). When I visited the url which executes the code, it waited 10s, it is fine.

But meanwhile, I visited a different url which only executes res.view(anohterView), it still waited for 10s. Does that mean sails.js execute synchronously, and the second url visiting is blocked by the first one?   Thanks!

```
someModel.findOne(modelId, function foundModel (err, model) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  if (!model) return next('Model doesn\'t exist.');

  function sleep(milliSeconds) {
      var startTime = new Date().getTime();
      while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
  }
  sleep(10000);

  res.view(Someview);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sleep function is blocking. Sails.js/nodejs is **single-threaded** so when your callback gets called, the thread is going to be blocked until it's finished.

If you want to 'sleep', you should be using [setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html):

```
someModel.findOne(modelId, function foundModel (err, model) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  if (!model) return next('Model doesn\'t exist.');

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      res.view(Someview);
    }
    10000
  );
});
```